# Is there any Chrome bookmarks API?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

I'd like to create a mobile app to work with Chrome bookmarks. But I couldn't find any information on how to work with Chrome bookmarks (not Google Bookmarks!!).

So is there any public or hidden API for that?

Comment: Chrome should make Open API for their own bookmark service. This is a little disappointing.

Comment: Governments should force Google to make this API open

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Bookmark API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/bookmarks/) which is available to Chrome extensions.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need an Chrome extension. I need a separate app running on iOS/WP7

Comment: That link now throws Error 404